# Spring 4 - Add a custom filter before BasicAuthenticationFilter, but only for certain URL patterns

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters, spring-4

I'm using Spring/Security 4.x with Java configuration.
I have several URLs. All of them are authenticated using BASIC authentication. Assume URL patterns are,

- /urlPattern1/**
- /urlPattern2/**
- /urlPattern3/**

Everything works fine so far.

Now I want to add a CORS filter only for the pattern /urlPattern3/**. If I add the custom CORS filter (I tried with few ways), I end up with `AccessDeniedException`. Ajax `pre-flight` request fails at the `BasicAuthenticationFilter` before it reaches to custom CORS filter.

I found that the custom filter which I added is at the bottom of the filter chain. Therefore I added it before `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

If I add the CORS filter using `http.addFilterBefore(new CORSFilter(), BasicAuthnticationFilter.class)`, incoming requests which match to every other URL patterns also go through this custom CORSFilter, which is not what I want. (But it works)

What I want to do *now* is,

1. Add a custom filter before any known filter (i.e. `BasicAuthenticationFilter.class`)
2. Specify URL patterns for that custom filter

Comment: If you resolve this, could you please share the answer. Thanks